# Generating a list of ternary numbers of length l with digit by digit inquiry possibility in python

Tags: python

I want to generate a list of ternary numbers of length l and save into a dictionary. Then I want the ability to compare these numbers digit by digit and do modifications too.

For example if the length `l=2`, the dictionary should contain numbers: `00,01,02,10,11,12,20,21,22`.

Then I want to do operations like comparing the `ith` digit of the `jth` entry in the dictionary with the `kth` digit of the `lth` entry. Like in the above list, comparing "0" of the entry "20" with "1" of the entry "21"

Also I should be able to sum up the digits of the `ith` entry of the dictionary. Like sum of the entry "11" = 2.

Please suggest me a way to do the above things. I am new to coding in python.

Here is my try but this doesn't give me 2 digit numbers. So a suggestion for how to go to tens place from ones place and so on, would be appreciated:

```
dict = {}
n = 0
dict[0] = 00
while (n < 9):
   dict[n+1]= (dict[n] +1) % 3
   if dict[n+1] = 2
   n = n +1

print (dict)   `
```

Comment: We don't do suggestions. We help you fix your code. Where is your code? See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Are you aware that a dictionary contains keys and values?

Comment: If you are new, start here and learn: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Comment: To start, look at [itertool product](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product).

Comment: I have put my code, please suggest the fix

Comment: if `l=3` should your result be `000-333`, or still `000-222`?

Comment: @AdamSmith The result should be 000-222. l gives the length of the string. If l=4, I want 0000 - 2222

Answer (score 1):

`itertools.product` seems to give you what you're looking for. It's often used in place of nested `for` loops, but has a convenient `repeat` kwarg that makes your life easier here.

```
l = 3  # that's a lower-case L. Never use that in code, though, it looks like a 1.

digits = itertools.product(range(3), repeat=l)

# is equivalent to

def my_product():
    """the same as above itertools.product if l==3"""
    for i in range(3):
        for j in range(3):
            for k in range(3):
                yield (i, j, k)
my_digits = my_product()  # YUCK!
```

This produces a *generator* (note: not a list!) that produces all the values you're looking for from `(0, 0, 0)` to `(2, 2, 2)`. To make a list, simply cast it to one.

```
digits = list(itertools.product(range(3), repeat=l))  # still a lower-case L. Still don't do this.
```

Then to compare digits, just use indexing like any 2D list.

```
first_value = digits[0]
first_digit = first_value[0]
assert first_digit == digits[0][0]

second_value = digits[1]
first_digit_of_second_value = second_value[0]
assert first_digit_of_second_value == digits[1][0]

if digits[0][0] == digits[1][0]:
    # that's these two:  v          v
    # digits ==         (0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 2), ...
    do_whatever_you_want()
```

If you want to specifically output `(0, 0, 0)` as `000`, you can write a function for that:

```
def sprint_tuple(tup):
    """Takes a tuple of digits and pretty Sprints them.

    >>> sprint_tuple((0, 0, 1))
    '001'
    """

    return ''.join([str(i) for i in tup])
```

then loop over your `digits` and print each:

```
>>> for tup in digits:
...     print(sprint_tuple(tup))
000
001
002
010
...
222
```